# Convert HTML5 chart to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, charts, itext

In my project we have planned to use charts . i have gone through various number of resources like

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

http://www.jchartfx.com/demo/27182674-0690-e211-84a5-0019b9e6b500

my problem is i have to conver the entire HTML page to PDF ehen user click on one button at the bottom of the page.

I have tried with ItextSharp and few other.they are mostly using the parser and i saw that few HTML tags are not supported in Itextsharp if that is the case how it will be for SVG tags .

this is the case in most of the third party tool how can i convert the page content(html + charts + images) into PDF.If anyone already did that kindly show me a link or path to achieve this.

note : charts we are planned to go with HTML5

Answer (score 1):

It is not free but you can try [ASPPDF](http://www.asppdf.net/)